# MySQL - Show people who haven't renewed products

Tags: mysql

Ok let me try to explain this the best I can. I am needing to generate a report for people that have not renewed a certain product (expiry of 1 year). We will call this membership.

I am only needing to pull the most recent rows for each "client_no", that match a string of product numbers. I dont want duplicate "client_no" records being pulled, however there can be multiple different "product_id"s.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM client_educational 
WHERE product_id IN ('1', '2', '3') 
AND order_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Database Design:

```
client_no    product          order_date

54321        Membership 3     2018-04-15
12345        Membership 2     2017-04-15
12345        Membership 1     2016-04-15
58428        Membership 2     2015-04-15
58428        Membership 1     2014-04-15
```

Current Results:

```
client_no    product          order_date

12345        Membership 2     2017-04-15
12345        Membership 1     2016-04-15
58428        Membership 2     2015-04-15
58428        Membership 1     2014-04-15
```

Desired Output:

```
client_no    product          order_date

12345        Membership 2     2017-04-15
58428        Membership 2     2015-04-15
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the following query.
The nested query condition is to eliminate the clients that have orders within last 1 year.

```
SELECT c.* FROM client_educational c 
WHERE c.product_id IN ('1', '2', '3') 
AND c.order_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND c.client_no NOT IN 
 (
  SELECT client_no FROM client_educational 
  WHERE product_id IN ('1', '2', '3') 
  AND order_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
 )
group by c.client_no order by c.order_date desc
```

Comment: Hey @Tanvir , thanks for your reply. This appears to be working for the most part...

However I am noticing some renewed products seeping through. 

For example user purchased product_id 1 on 2017-01-24 then purchased product_id 1 again on 2018-03-04. 

can we make it to where it won't show at all if it has any of these product id's with order date less than one year ago?

if i need to provide more information, please let me know.

Comment: @Jon - I have edited the query. The nested query in the condition should work to prevent from pulling the clients with orders within a year.